# C# Microsoft Interlop Slow-Take range into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, datatable, datarow

I have the following code in c# which reads from an Excel file using Microsoft Interop

```
Application xlApp;
Workbook xlWorkBook;
Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Range range;

string str;

xlApp = new Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\\telltales.xlsx");
xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int Cnum = 4; Cnum < 12; Cnum++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Convert.ToString((range.Cells[2, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2)));
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
for (int Rnum = 10; Rnum <= 45; Rnum++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int Cnum = 4; Cnum < 12; Cnum++)
    {
        if ((range.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
        {
            dr[Cnum - 2] = (range.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
        }
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

At the end, the data is displayed in a DataTable. The Code is working fine, the only problem is if I have too many rows the reading is very, very slow because it  **reads cell by cell**.

Is there any way that I could get all the data into an array, so I can display it into the DataTable easy and **fast**?

Comment: Have a look at EPPlus. It's an open source library available via NuGet that handles Excel's .xlsx files using only managed code. Should be much faster than interop.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExpertXls.ExcelLibrary/

Comment: @EricJ Since i started with Microsoft Interlop i would like to continue with it. I guess it would be easy to get data into an array, than recreating the reading from scratch in EPPlus.